# swith to circular list to shift easier

Tags: java, arrays, shift, circular-buffer

I have a private arraylist with classes that include two longs, a float and a BigDecimal. As new data comes in I currently am removing the oldest element, shifiting all other elements over, and then adding the newest element. I think this is taking up a lot of memory uncessearly. So is there anyway to make this a circle, so I don't need to shift over elements in the array?

I'll include the relevenat parts of my code below:

```
private ArrayList<privStat> MyList = new ArrayList<privStat>();
public class privStat {
   long Stat1;
   long Stat2;
   float Stat3;
   BigDecimal Stat4;
}

NewStat = new privStat(//new message)
if (MyList.size() - 1 < 10) {
   MyList.add(NewStat);
} else {
   Mylist.remove(0);
   Mylist.add(NewStat);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a queue instead of a list?

Comment: Isn't linkedlist sufficient for this purpose? If I remember correctly, it has good performance for insert/delete operations.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to implement a queue in Java.  Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html).

Java also provides a LinkedList class which can be easily implemented as a queue.  [Here's an example.](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/how-to-implement-a-queue.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a first-in, first-out data structure such as a `Queue` like `LinkedList`? This will allow you to add at the back of the queue, and remove from the front. Both operations will take constant time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question right, you have to see to Queue class, I think it work more efficiently behind the scenes. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Or you can use array and mod operation (but it will be a circle, not queue):

```
PrivStat[] privStats=new PrivStat[10]();
int i=0;
```

and use next code for add:

```
privStats[i]=newStat;
i=(++i) % 10;
```